# How to append text to a text file in C++?

Tags: c++, filestream

How to append text to a text file in C++? And create a new text file if it does not already exist and append text to it if it does exist.

Comment: http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/

Answer (score 382, accepted):

You need to specify the append open mode like

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {  
  std::ofstream outfile;

  outfile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite
  outfile << "Data"; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to close the file manually, as it does so upon destruction. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748014/. Also, <iostream> is not being used in the example.

Comment: You can use ios::app in place of ios_base::app

Comment: Can use `std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app` instead of `std::ios_base::app`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Comment: You can also do more in the constructor if you want to cut down on code: std::ofstream outfile("test.txt", std::ios_base::app);

Comment: You don't need to specify the `out` flag explicitly when using `std::ofstream`, it always uses the `out` flag implicitly for you.  Same with the `in` flag for `std::ifstream`. You would have to specify the `in` and `out` flags explicitly if you were using `std::fstream` instead.

Comment: Also instead of `std::ios_base::app` you can use shorter `std::ios::app`.

Comment: @TrevorHickey you can use 8 instead of ios::app 

Answer (score 18):

I use this code. It makes sure that file gets created if it doesn't exist and also adds bit of error checks.

```
static void appendLineToFile(string filepath, string line)
{
    std::ofstream file;
    //can't enable exception now because of gcc bug that raises ios_base::failure with useless message
    //file.exceptions(file.exceptions() | std::ios::failbit);
    file.open(filepath, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    if (file.fail())
        throw std::ios_base::failure(std::strerror(errno));

    //make sure write fails with exception if something is wrong
    file.exceptions(file.exceptions() | std::ios::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    file << line << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>

 FILE * pFileTXT;
 int counter

int main()
{
 pFileTXT = fopen ("aTextFile.txt","a");// use "a" for append, "w" to overwrite, previous content will be deleted

 for(counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
 fprintf (pFileTXT, "%c", characterarray[counter] );// character array to file

 fprintf(pFileTXT,"\n");// newline

 for(counter=0;counter<9;counter++)
 fprintf (pFileTXT, "%d", digitarray[counter] );    // numerical to file

 fprintf(pFileTXT,"A Sentence");                   // String to file

 fprintf (pFileXML,"%.2x",character);              // Printing hex value, 0x31 if character= 1

 fclose (pFileTXT); // must close after opening

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is C way, not C++.

Comment: @Dženan. C being a subset of C++ does not invalidate this approach.

Comment: @Osaid C is not a subset of C++. Compilers compile its code for backward compatibility. Many C-valid things are not C++-valid things, e.g. VLA.

Comment: but if we want to append text in the middle of file? with C style? using FILE *?? "a+" or "a" with fseek() and ftell() didn't worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `fstream` and open it with the `std::ios::app` flag. Have a look at the code below and it should clear your head.

```
...
fstream f("filename.ext", f.out | f.app);
f << "any";
f << "text";
f << "written";
f << "wll";
f << "be append";
...
```

You can find more information about the open modes [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) and about fstreams [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Comment: and yet he doesnt have  std::ios::app...

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it like this

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main(){   
    std::ofstream ost {outputfile, std::ios_base::app};
    
    ost.open(outputfile);
    ost << "something you want to add to your outputfile";
    ost.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Passing the filename to the `ofstream` constructor opens the file immediately, so calling `open()` afterwards is redundant.

Comment: also `ost.close();` is redundant as it's called in the `std::ofstream` destructor.