# Keeping previous record, how to add new text in textfile using fstream in c++

Tags: c++, save, text-files, fstream

In C++ I have made a program which writes given data into a text file (notepad). The problem is when I restart my program and enter other data then it clears the previous one and adds new data.

**I want to keep my previous data safe, and add new data in a new line in text file.**

For example,

I wrote "*I am a programmer*" in my program.
Now my text file will show this:`I am a programmer`

Now if I restart my program and write "*I am unemployed*". Then textfile shows this: `I am unemployed`.

But I want my file to be:

`I am a programmer`

`I am unemployed`

Please, Help...

Comment: You 're probably missing the `std::fstream::app` flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append text to a text file in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to open the file with the append flag. If you're using fstream, it looks something like this:

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

fstream outfile = fstream("myfilename.txt", ios_base::app)
```

See reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

Comment: `fstream.h` is outdated, so you should be using just `<fstream>`, and `using namespace std;` should not be used that much. Also, why are you allocating the class on the heap? This means that the file has to be deleted eventually.

Comment: Is it not good practice to use 'code' using namespace std 'code' in isolated code examples where it makes things easier to read? Other suggestions noted and answer revised.