# How to refresh an opened .txt file in c++?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I now want to create an application that will open a `.txt` file and write something in it, then refresh the `.txt` file and write something else in the file.

This is what I have done so far:

```
ofstream file("file.txt");
    system("start file.txt");
    file << "Hello";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sleep_for(1s);
        file << ". " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

and these are libraries and namespaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace this_thread;
using namespace chrono_literals;
```

Comment: You mean like a flush?

Comment: file.flush() should do it, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: `endl` will flush the file.

Comment: by refresh I mean to open and close the file(to uppdate the file)

Comment: I do not want to go to another row, I want to write something in several phases (to a second to show up " . ")

Comment: but how do I do that?

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, then you do mean flush().