# How do I leave text in a file?

Tags: c++

So I created a program , when you write " user.create " in the console it will tell you to input a name and a password , after that , the username and the password are being written in the text file " nice.txt " , but every time you start the program , " nice.txt " is cleared , how can I leave text there and read it when I need to ?!

here is the sample code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
fstream file_to_create;
file_to_create.open("nice.txt");
ifstream read("nice.txt");
ofstream out("nice.txt");
    string input = " ";
    while (1) {
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "app.exit")
            return 0;
        else if (input == "user.create") {
            string name, password;
            cout << "create user->\n";
            cout << "name:";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "password:";
            cin >> password;
            out << name << '\n' << password << '\n';
            cout << "user created.\n";
        } else if (input == "user.access") {
            string name, password;
            cout << "access user->\n";
            cout << "name:";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "password:";
            cin >> password;
            string look_name, look_password;
            bool found = 0;
            while (read >> look_name >> look_password) {
                if (look_name == name &&        look_password == password) {
                    cout << "user " << look_name    << " is now connected.\n";
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
            if (!found)cout << "user not found.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

basically when you type in " user.access " it should read text from " nice.txt "
which is empty because it's cleared every time you execute the .exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append text to a text file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your file with `append mode`. When you open to writing it, the default mode is `std::ios::out`. This mode moves the cursor to the beginning of the file and if you write some text on the file, it will overlay the old data.

You need to use `std::ios::app`. This mode moves the cursor to the end of the file, avoiding the overlay.

Change:

```
ofstream out("nice.txt");
```

to:

```
ofstream out("nice.txt", std::ios::app);
```

You can read more about this [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).