# How to preserve old data in the file when adding new data

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How do I add new data to the file without destroying the old data? The data contains name and age fields. Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char data[100];
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("afile.txt");
    cout << "Writing to the file" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your name: "; 
    cin.getline(data, 100);
    outfile << data << endl;
    cout << "Enter your age: "; 
    cin >> data;
    cin.ignore();
    outfile << data << endl;
    outfile.close();

    ifstream infile; 
    infile.open("afile.txt"); 
    cout << "Reading from the file" << endl; 
    infile >> data; 
    cout << data << endl;
    infile >> data; 
    cout << data << endl; 
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear. Do you want to append data into a file?

Comment: It sounds like a duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: yes i want to append data with the data in the file

Answer (score 0):

According to [std::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/)

> `void open (const string& filename,  ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);`

where [std::ios_base::openmode](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/) is one of the following

- `app` (append) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream before each output operation.
- `ate` (at end) Set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream on opening.
- `binary`  (binary) Consider stream as binary rather than text.
- `in`  (input) Allow input operations on the stream.
- `out` (output) Allow output operations on the stream.
- `trunc`   (truncate) Any current content is discarded, assuming a length of zero on opening.

You can combine openmodes with `|`

```
std::ios_base::openmode::out | std::ios_base::openmode::app
```

This will open file for writing, appending data to the end.

Comment: i dont understand . ok now u said i write  this (std::ios_base::openmode::out | std::ios_base::openmode::app)? to solve my problem