# C++ Create file for each struct{person} entry

Tags: c++, struct

I've run into an issue with writing to a file and it being over written every time the program is ran. I can't seem to find a solution for the in.txt to stop wiping itself, so I decided to do something even better but more complicated.

Question: What can I look into to create a file for each entry from a person. I could retrieve the first and surname to name the file I guess.

I have a struct like this -

```
struct ClientInfo {

    string first_name;
    string middle_name;
    string surname_name;
    string date_birth;
    string telephonenumber;
    string first_line;
    string second_line;
    string zip_post; // zip code or postcode
    string Country;

};
```

When I start the program it records it into `ofstream file_in("in.txt")` successfully but then it's automatically erased at the start of next entry.

Comment: What you are looking for is [How to append text to a file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

> ... but then it's automatically erased at the start of the next entry

To solve this issue, you need to use `append` mode not write. Try the following:

```
std::ofstream outfile;

outfile.open("myfile.txt", std::ios_base::app); // append instead of overwrite
outfile << "text";
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I've tried that but it still over writes, could this possibly be because I'm using io redirection?

Comment: streambuf* stream_buffer_cout = cout.rdbuf();
 streambuf* stream_buffer_cin = cin.rdbuf();
 
 streambuf* stream_buffer_file = file.rdbuf();

 cout.rdbuf(stream_buffer_file);

 cout << "this line written to file" << endl;

 cout.rdbuf(stream_buffer_file);
 cout << "this line is written to screen" << endl;

 copy(p_vec.begin(), p_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<ClientInfo>(std::cout, " "));