# How do you sequentially write to a csv in C++

Tags: c++, csv, export-to-csv

I was just wondering how to write a list in a csv for my dice game in C++

Here is what i have so far:

```
void csv_export1(int score)
{
    ofstream my_file;
    my_file.open("score.csv");
    my_file << USERNAME << "," << score <<"\n" << endl;
}


void csv_read()
{
    fstream fin;
    fin.open("score.csv");
}
```

Why does it write over the original score?
Many thanks.

Comment: You can fix this by setting the flags to append however my advice is open  the file 1 time instead of reopening on each line. Related to appending: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c)

Comment: Sometimes it helps to re-read your question when you are done writing. In this case, you started with "how to write", but ended with "why overwrite". Since you've demonstrated the ability to write to a file, the latter seems to be your real question. So lead off with that. Try something more like *"I was wondering why, when I write to a csv file, I overwrite the original data instead of adding a new line."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, opening a file for output will truncate the it, overwriting its contents. `std::ostream::open` can take two arguments, the latter of which can be used to tell it to append data to the file, instead of this default behaviour. See [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) for more details on what `std::ios::out` and `std::ios::app` are doing in the following example.

So, your program might look more like this:

```
void csv_export1(const int &score) {
    std::ofstream my_file;
    my_file.open("score.csv", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    my_file << "USERNAME" << "," << score << std::endl;
}
```

On another note, as has been mentioned elsewhere, this approach of opening the file each time the function is called can be costly. A more efficient approach might be to open the file elsewhere, and pass it to the function by reference.