# Get number of lines of a file via for loop

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I have a file I read , and I want to start by counting the number of lines, so I did

I want to count the number of lines in a input file

```
void foo(ifstream &MyList) 
{
    int nb_lines = 0;
    string line;
    for (nb_lines; getline(MyList,line); nb_lines++) {};
    [...]
}
```

Which is I guess not the right way to do it, but it does the work.
How should I have done ?

In addition, compiler tells me that `statement has no effect`, which is false (value of nb_lines is changed). Can I make him understand that? ---> just use `for (; getline(MyList,line); nb_lines++) {};`

Comment: The compiler yells at you about `nb_lines;`, not `nb_lines++;`.

Comment: that right, I can just remove it thank

Comment: [How to count lines of a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072795/how-to-count-lines-of-a-file-in-c)

Comment: "---> just use for (; getline(MyList,line); nb_lines++) {};" if this is supposed to be an answer you should post it as answer but you should not include it in the question, if not, I dont understand what the question is about

Comment: sayanel, If the file was only 3 bytes `"abc"` with no trailing `'\n'`, would you count that a s 1 or 0 line file?

Comment: @sebastian the `std::count` approach is invalid and cannot handle a proper count where there is no POSIX `eof`. Using `getline` and a counter provides a proper count regardless. There are a number of common editors that do not write a POSIX `eof` (e.g. a `'\n'` after the final line) even today. The `std::count` approach fails to count the final line without a line-ending.

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(ifstream &MyList) {
    int nb_lines = 0;
    string line;
    for (; getline(MyList,line); nb_lines++);
    // alternatively
    while( getline(MyList,line) )
        ++nb_lines;
}
```

Thats enought normally.