# Does ofstream close its files automatically?

Tags: c++, ofstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [do I need to close a std::fstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802494/do-i-need-to-close-a-stdfstream)

```
int main() {
    ofstream a("a.txt");
    a << "A" << endl;
    //a.close();
}
```

This works fine, but isn't it necessary to close the file at the end of the program?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802494/do-i-need-to-close-a-stdfstream (and even that one is a duplicate)

Comment: @Dirk I just looked for ofstream not ifstream, I'll be searching broadly next next time. Close my question if you wish.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`ofstream` will close files when its destructor is called, i.e. when it goes out of scope.  However, calling `close()` certainly doesn't do any harm and expresses your intentions to maintenance programmers.

Calling `close()` also allows you to check if the close() was successful because you can then also check the `failbit`:

https://cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/

Answer (score 9):

It is necessary to call close if you want to check the result (success or failure).

Otherwise, the stream's destructor will attempt to close the file for you.