# ofstream returning error "No matching function to call std::basic_ofstream<char>::close(const char [14])"

Tags: c++, c++11, ofstream

Need help fixing my code, not sure what's wrong. I'm using C++11, trying to write a vector to a file by individually writing each struct. The section of code returning an error is:

```
string craigSave = "craigSave.txt";
ofstream file(craigSave.c_str());
file.open("craigSave.txt");
for (int i=0; i<finalVector.size(); i++){
    file << finalVector[i]<<endl;
}
file.close("craigSave.txt");
cout<<"Thanks for shopping!"<<endl;
done = true;
```

The error returned is on the "file.close" line and is:

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream::close(const char [14])'

I research on this error seems to point to needing to use char* as an argument instead of a string, but I'm using C++11, so it should accept strings. Also it is strange that there is no error for the file.open line, as all research shows the error being there, not at file.close

Comment: `close` doesn't take any parameters. Where are you doing your research? (Wherever it is, go [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) instead.)

Comment: The constructor opened the file. There's no need for the call to `file.open()`. The destructor will close the file; there's no need for the call to `file.close()`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `file.close();`, there's no need to pass the file name again.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/.

Also, `ofstream`s are RAII objects, which means that the file will automatically be closed once the `ofstream` object goes out of scope (see [do I need to close a std::fstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802494/do-i-need-to-close-a-stdfstream)):

```
{
    ofstream out("name");
    // do something with out...
} // out.close is called automatically
```

Comment: Better yet, remove the line altogether.

Comment: True, I'll expand the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question, since I haven't specified a location for that file, where does it look for it? In the same folder as the .cpp itself?>

Comment: @SamBerger In the application's working directory, ie. the directory you started the application from.

Comment: @SamBerger BTW, if the answer solved your problem, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.