# File input not working as expected

Tags: c++, ifstream

in main:

```
ifstream file("text.txt");
string line;
while (file) {
    file>>line;
    cout<<line<<endl;
}
```

in text.txt:

```
hello
goodbye
```

output:

```
hello
goodbye
goodbye
```

Why is the last line printed twice?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/c-read-file-line-by-line

Comment: @pb2q That's great, but that question isn't the same as the question I was asking. I know there are other (maybe better) ways to do what I want, but I want to know why _this_ way doesn't work, and why it does what it does.

Comment: I understand why "hello" is printed twice, but not why "goodbye is omitted. I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: Huh... Well thanks for trying. Can you tell me why hello is printed twice? Cause I don't understand that part.

Comment: when I compile it, I get:
    `hello
    goodbye
    goodbye`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to manually close a ifstream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748014/do-i-need-to-manually-close-a-ifstream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplication: When you read 'goodbye' for the first time, you don't know that you reached the end of file and go to the next iteration. Then fail to read, get `eof` bit set, but print out the current value of `line`, which remains to be 'goodbye'.