# Can a file stream destructor throw an exception in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, throw, filestreams

Can a file stream destructor throw an exception, e.g., if file closing operation fails?

```
   auto f = new std::ofstream("data.txt");
   f->exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit | std::ofstream::badbit);
   ...
   delete f; // May throw?
```

Can I prevent such exceptions by closing a stream manually?

```
   auto f = new std::ofstream("data.txt");
   f->exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit | std::ofstream::badbit);
   ...
   f->close();
   delete f; // May throw?
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/748014/72178.

Comment: No standard class throws from its destructor, and neither should yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing from a destructor is dangerous and should be avoided. No object of the C++ standard library throws from its destructor. The C++ language implicitly assumes that destructors are declared as `noexcept`.

In fact, this is the only difference between [`std::basic_filebuf<>::close()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/close) and [`std::basic_filebuf<>::~std::basic_filebuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/%7Ebasic_filebuf): the latter calls `close()` but catches any exception without re-throwing. So, if you want to catch problems with closing the underlying file, you could explicitly call `ofstream::rdbuf()->close()`. However `ofstream::close()` effectively calls `rdbuf()->close()` and catches any exceptions. In this case, it sets the `failbit` and *iff* you have set the stream's exception mask accordingly (via `ofstream::exceptions()`, as you did in your question) throws a (different) exception of type [`std::ios_base::failure`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure).

Thus, to summarize:

- if you use RAII (i.e. the destructor) to close the file, no
  exceptions will be propagated out of the destructor, even if the
  underlying file could not be closed cleanly. In this case, the
  failbit will be set.
- if you explicitly `close()` the `std::ofstream`, then, depending on the exception mask of the stream, `std::ios_base::failure` may be thrown upon encountering a problem with closing the file.

Comment: @Holt thanks. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.