# Should I close a file when it wasn't able open?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

Should I close a file when it wasn't able to open?

Should I write this:

```
std::ifstream file(DATA_PATH);
if (!file.good()) //File doesn't exist
{
    //do something
}
else //file exists
{
    //do something
    file.close();
}
```

Or should I write:

```
std::ifstream file(DATA_PATH);
if (!file.good()) //File doesn't exist
{
    //do something
}
else //file exists
{
    //do something
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Related: [Do I need to manually close an ifstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/748014/2602718) (spoiler alert: **no**)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not necessary to be done explicitly. (File) streams are closed when going out of scope implicitly always.

The `close()` function of a `std::iostream()` also is an *idempotent* operation, and never will harm the streams state beyond the stream gets closed (or never was successfully opened).

Comment: Sorry, can't help it, but to quote from Friends: "`Monica`: Hey Joey, what would you do if you were omnipotent? `Joey`: Probably kill myself. `Monica`: Excuse me? `Joey`: Hey, if little Joey's dead, then I've got no reason to live. `Ross`: Joey, omnipotent. `Joey`: You are? I'm so sorry."

Comment: @SergeyA _Idempotent_ and _omnipotent_ mean quite different things.

Comment: Well, I am aware :) Just couldn't help the joke

Answer (score 0):

You DO NOT need to call `close()` if the stream fails to open. On the other hand, it is not harmful to do so, either.

Comment: To be fair, you don't need to call `close` in either case. I'm not even sure why this function exists

Comment: @Quentin Do you need to `close` before `open`ing a different file? Might be a use case for it, to reuse an instance. Though you could just construct another instance and move assign it like any other value type, but I'm not sure what the overhead for that might be.

Comment: @Quentin Well, depends on the code structure and workflow. There are certainly use cases where it makes sense to call close() independently of the variable's scope.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "*Though you could just construct another instance and move assign it like any other value type*" - `open()`/`close()` predate the introduction of move semantics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. I sometimes forget that dark age existed.

Comment: @Quentin At least theoretically there is another use case: close() could throw an exception on error - whereas the destructor simply can't. If there is any error whilst closing a file, failbit will be set. Iff your stream has enabled exceptions (not the default case!) an exception will be thrown for errors that happen during closing a file Such errors are simply ignored during destructors!

Comment: @MFH fair enough.